# WSO2ESB error when posting JSON request over TCP

Tags: json, tcp, esb, wso2-esb

Trying to post a JSON request over TCP. WSO2 ESB has been configured as follows to use TCP transport (in axis2.xml).

```
<transportReceiver class="org.apache.axis2.transport.tcp.TCPTransportListener" name="tcp"></transportReceiver>
```

Added the proxy service as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="TcpToHttpProxy" startOnLoad="true" transports="tcp" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<target>
    <endpoint name="endpoint_urn_uuid_71d9f268-1f33-48f2-bd89-439ac88095d1">
        <address uri="http://localhost:82/api/v1/reservations"/>
    </endpoint>
    <inSequence>
        <log level="full"/>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
        <send/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence/>
</target>
<parameter name="transport.tcp.contentType">application/json</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.tcp.port">6060</parameter>
</proxy>
```

However, getting the below error when posting the request:

```
[2017-01-16 17:48:52,094]  INFO - LogMediator To: , WSAction: urn:mediate, SOAPAction: urn:mediate, MessageID: urn:uuid:25D317F2A1C891B19D1484569132104, Direction: request, Payload: 
{"patient": {
"name": "John Doe",
"dob": "1940-03-19",
"ssn": "234-23-525",
"address": "California",
"phone": "8770586755",
"email": "johndoe@gmail.com"},
  "doctor": "thomas collins",
  "hospital": "abc"}
[2017-01-16 17:48:52,099] ERROR - JsonUtil #writeJsonStream. Could not write JSON stream. MessageID: urn:uuid:0109653d-e79c-4143-98b9-0053b565bb19. Error>> Stream closed.
[2017-01-16 17:48:52,099]  INFO - AxisEngine [MessageContext: logID=5cdd488a83f3b09fc0c3e3f949982e3d155cbcf0d761edcd] Could not write JSON stream.
[2017-01-16 17:48:52,100] ERROR - AsyncCallback Could not write JSON stream.
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Could not write JSON stream.
at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeAsJson(JsonUtil.java:249)
at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter.writeTo(JsonStreamFormatter.java:61)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.sendRequestContent(PassThroughHttpSender.java:389)
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:256)
at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine$TransportNonBlockingInvocationWorker.run(AxisEngine.java:626)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Could not write JSON stream.
at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeJsonStream(JsonUtil.java:833)
at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeAsJson(JsonUtil.java:237)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed.
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.available(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.available(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1792)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1769)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1744)
at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.writeJsonStream(JsonUtil.java:823)
... 8 more
[2017-01-16 17:48:52,101]  WARN - AsyncCallback Executing fault handler due to exception encountered
[2017-01-16 17:48:52,101]  WARN - EndpointContext Endpoint : endpoint_urn_uuid_71d9f268-1f33-48f2-bd89-439ac88095d1 with address http://localhost:82/api/v1/reservations will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed
[2017-01-16 17:48:52,102]  WARN - EndpointContext Suspending endpoint : endpoint_urn_uuid_71d9f268-1f33-48f2-bd89-439ac88095d1 with address http://localhost:82/api/v1/reservations - current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Mon Jan 16 17:49:22 IST 2017
```

It looks like JSON request is passed to ESB as it logs JSON object properly. However, it does not pass JSON request to backend service (Web API).

Could someone please advise me to fix this issue?